# overflow-y auto hides content

Tags: html, css, overflow

with `overflow-y:auto`

[image]

with `overflow-y:scroll`

[image]

Is there some way to have scrollbar if it overflows (and not hiding the content), but at the same time remove it if it does not overflow?

Current css:

```
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden; <-- do not want horizontal scroll under any circumstances, want the div to respond to the content
```

Comment: It looks like your code should work. There should be no scroll bar unless the content height exceeds your 400px max of your parent element. Are you asking about the positioning the scroll bar so that it does not cover any of the content when the scroll bar is visible?

Comment: please add your html

Comment: @AliasVarghese, it's really cumbersome to include (and do the needed obfuscation) since it is embedded in so many levels and is created by angular. As well as other custom css. I've tried to make a minified example, but it does not come near the result i'm having right now unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a negative `margin-right` on your list and a parent container element with a positive `padding-right` to compensate for the negative child margin.

```css
.container {
    width:100px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
ul {
    max-height:100px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.list-one {
}
.list-two {
    margin-right:-10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul class="list-one">
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-two">
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, result is not 100% perfect, but it's good enough :)